# JSF ReRender support with selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces, ajax4jsf, rerender

I have a JSF page on which I want to have a checkbox that, when clicked, will add/remove certain other form fields from the page. Here is the (simplified) code I currently have for the checkbox:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="showComponentToReRender" value="#{backingBean.showComponentToReRender}">
    <a4j:support event="onsubmit" reRender="componentToReRender" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Here is the code for the component I want to hide:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="componentToReRender" value="#{backingBean.value}" rendered="#{valuesList.rowCount>1 &amp;&amp; backingBean.showComponentToReRender}">
   <s:selectItems value="#{valuesList}" var="value"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Currently, clicking the checkbox does nothing; that "selectOneMenu" will not go away. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap the `componentToReRender` in either:

`<h:panelGroup id="componentToReRenderWrapper">`

or

`<a4j:outputPanel id="componentToReRenderWrapper">`

So, effectively you will have:

```
<h:panelGroup id="componentToReRenderWrapper">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="componentToReRender" value="#{backingBean.value}" rendered="#{valuesList.rowCount>1 &amp;&amp; backingBean.showComponentToReRender}">
       <s:selectItems value="#{valuesList}" var="value"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and change the `reRender="componentToReRenderWrapper"` in case you use `panelGroup`, or remove that attribute, in case you use `outputPanel`.

Found the exact explanation in the [RichFaces](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.2.GA/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html) docs:

> Most common problem with using reRender is pointing it to the component that has a  "rendered"   attribute. Note, that JSF does not mark the place in the browser DOM where the outcome of the component should be placed in case the  "rendered"   condition returns false. Therefore, after the component becomes rendered during the Ajax request, RichFaces delivers the rendered code to the client, but does not update a page, because the place for update is unknown. You need to point to one of the parent components that has no  "rendered"   attribute. As an alternative, you can wrap the component with     layout="none" .

Comment: it seems it does actually, but the rendering is a bit tricky. I updated my answer with details from the docs

Comment: Interesting... I'll try this on Monday morning.

Comment: Wrapping the components to be rerendered in a h:panelGroup worked as you expected. The only problem I'm having now is that the boxes take a few seconds to appear/disappear and I'm not sure how to let the user know their change is being affected. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to set ajaxRendered="true" on the a4j:outputPanel